# Insert a new row on table after updating another table

Tags: mysql

This is what I am looking for ,I want to insert into my customers table after status column in payment table is updated as "success".
This is my payment table

```
id  customerid  status
1    789999      success
2    678899       failure
```

This is my customer table

```
id name   customerid   
1  batman 789999
```

I am looking to insert into my customer table the data of client which have status as success through ,trigger  . Like if for customer id 789999 if the status is updated as success ,I want to insert a new row in my customer table that has data of customer for whom the status just changed to success ,not for failure
This is what I have tried so far..

```
  CREATE TRIGGER insert_customer  AFTER UPDATE
ON payment FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (NEW.payment_status ='success')
THEN
INSERT INTO `customers`( `customerid`,  `package`, `comdate`, `expiry`,`name`, `email`, `phone`, `address`,`package_details`) VALUES (new.cutomerid,new.product,new.date_t,date_add(new.date_t,INTERVAL 365 day),new.name,new.email,new.phone,new.addresss,new.package_details);
END
```

Comment: what did you try so far ?

Comment: please share the complete trigger code.

Comment: I have shared ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Assuming **col** is a column in **Tab** table:

create or replace TRIGGER NewInvoice
    AFTER INSERT ON Tab
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
     INSERT INTO INVOICES(id, champ1, champ2, champ3, champ4)
      values ('1', '1', :new.col, '1', '1');
    END;

Comment: Its so easy to create trigger after insert ,I am looking for trigger that inserts after "update"